# Accessing a kererized remote HBASE cluster from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, pyspark, remote-access, kerberos

I'm attempting to read data from a kerberized HBASE instance from Spark using the [Hortonworks SPARK-ON-HBASE connector](http://hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/).  My cluster configuration essentially looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvn9W.png):  I am submitting my spark jobs from a client machine to a remote Spark standalone cluster, and that job is attempting to read data from a *seperate* HBASE cluster.

If I bypass the standalone cluster by running Spark with master=local[*] directly on my client, I can access the remote HBASE cluster no problem as long as I first kinit from the client.  However, when I set my master as the remote cluster with all other configs the same, I receive a null pointer exception at `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(UserProvider.java:43)` (full stack trace below)

Has anyone accomplished a similar architecture that can perhaps lend some 
insight?  Despite the logs not saying anything about an authentication issue, I have a hunch that I may be having an authentication issue when accessing HBASE from the non-kerberized Spark cluster.

---

Full stack trace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(UserProvider.java:43)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.init(HBaseResources.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.liftedTree1$1(HBaseResources.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.acquire(HBaseResources.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.acquire(HBaseResources.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.releaseOnException(HBaseResources.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.releaseOnException(HBaseResources.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.getScanner(HBaseResources.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anonfun$7.apply(HBaseTableScan.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anonfun$7.apply(HBaseTableScan.scala:266)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.leaf(ParArray.scala:658)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:56)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.tryLeaf(ParArray.scala:650)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:165)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:514)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(UserProvider.java:43)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.init(HBaseResources.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.liftedTree1$1(HBaseResources.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.acquire(HBaseResources.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.acquire(HBaseResources.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.ReferencedResource$class.releaseOnException(HBaseResources.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.releaseOnException(HBaseResources.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.TableResource.getScanner(HBaseResources.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anonfun$7.apply(HBaseTableScan.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anonfun$7.apply(HBaseTableScan.scala:266)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.leaf(ParArray.scala:658)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:56)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.tryLeaf(ParArray.scala:650)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:165)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:514)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
```

Comment: If you are using Kryo, try remove it! You can read more here: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/17 by: @rafael-mendes

Answer (score 0):

You have a configuration problem where the hbase.client.userprovider.class configuration is not available.  You will need to make sure hbase libs and conf files are on the path of your spark executor.

```
      private static final String USER_PROVIDER_CONF_KEY = "hbase.client.userprovider.class";

  /**
   * Instantiate the {@link UserProvider} specified in the configuration and set the passed
   * configuration via {@link UserProvider#setConf(Configuration)}
   * @param conf to read and set on the created {@link UserProvider}
   * @return a {@link UserProvider} ready for use.
   */
  public static UserProvider instantiate(Configuration conf) {
    Class<? extends UserProvider> clazz =
        conf.getClass(USER_PROVIDER_CONF_KEY, UserProvider.class, UserProvider.class);
    return ReflectionUtils.newInstance(clazz, conf);
  }
```

Comment: I've used sparkContext.addFile to add hbase-site.xml to the executor class path, and I'm including hbase-client.jar as well -- is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on that symptom (but the root cause may not be the same) and found a ***very dirty workaround*** that you may not want to try.

*$$ Context $$*    **Cloudera** distro, HBase 1.2.0-CDH5.7.0

---

*$$ Issue #1 $$*    Some code clean-ups in the Apache / HortonWorks distros have not been ported to the Cloudera distro, e.g.
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCaching(I)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan;`

*$$ Workaround #1 $$*

- Download the HBase client JARs from the [Horton repo](http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/hbase/) -- specifically "client", "common" and "protocol" -- for version 1.1.2 *(that's the dependency shown in the POM for Spark-HBase module)*.
- Add these JARs (and directory `/etc/hbase/conf/`) to `spark.driver.extraClassPath` along with Spark-HBase JAR.
- Ship these JARs to the executors via command-line option `--jars` along with Spark-HBase JAR
  (and don't forget directory `/etc/hbase/conf/` in `spark.executor.extraClassPath` if the conf is present on all YARN nodes; otherwise find a way to ship the XML to a directory in their container CLASSPATH)

---

*$$ Issue #2 $$*    Somehow, in YARN mode, the Spark executors do not generate correctly the HBase configuration that is passed to methods `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.instantiate(Configuration)` and `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(Configuration, boolean, ExecutorService, User)`, hence
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

*$$ Workaround #2 $$*

- Download the HBase source code from [GitHub, branch 1.1](https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/branch-1.1/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase) for these two classes
- Patch the code to make sure that whenever the `conf` argument is NULL, it is replaced silently with a call to `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create()`
- Compile both classes, and replace the original `.class` executables in the appropriate JARs with your patched versions

**It would certainly make more sense to patch the Spark-HBase plug-in** (cf. comment from *ray3888* in [that post](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/17)) **but Scala makes me puke** so I stick to plain'old Java.